# SQL How to flag a given sessionID based on values from another column

Tags: sql, databricks

Forgive me I'm not massively familiar with SQL to do the below. But would love to learn the process of how to do it if possible.

I only have one table: Table name - SessionTracker

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

bundleID                   | sessionId |                  deviceID |                                   eventType |          codeValue 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

com.package.random          3871207406642403679         333333-00000-0000-00000-000000000000000       REQUEST                1
com.package.random          3871207406642403679         333333-00000-0000-00000-000000000000000       EVENT                  1
com.package.random          3871207406642403679         333333-00000-0000-00000-000000000000000       RESPONSE               1
com.package.random          3245233406642403679         000000-00000-0000-00000-000000000000000       REQUEST                1
com.package.random          3245233406642403679         000000-00000-0000-00000-000000000000000       EVENT                  2
com.package.random          3245233406642403679         000000-00000-0000-00000-000000000000000       RESPONSE               2
com.package.random          871207406643e243433         000000-00000-0000-00000-000000000000000       REQUEST                1
com.package.random2         3243254325454535422         111111-00000-0000-00000-000000000000000       REQUEST                1
com.package.random3         4353453452525252465         222222-00000-0000-00000-000000000000000       REQUEST                1
com.package.random4         3453656456353252345         111111-00000-0000-00000-000000000000000       REQUEST                1
com.package.random5         4567568765745634563         111111-00000-0000-00000-000000000000000       REQUEST                1
```

I'd like to

```
Select all the sessions where the codeValue was different within that session.
```

From the example above:

I want to check is if a session which consists of request, event & response has a different value in one of each. Like the sessionId above (3871207406642403679) the code value is 1 in each so this wouldn't be flagged.

The second sessionId (3245233406642403679) the code value in one of the request, event & response has the code value 2 for event and response, so this would be flagged.

I'm hoping a query in databricks would work, is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL, you could do this with aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select sessionId
from mytable
group by sessionId
having min(codeValue) <> max(codeValue)
```

This gives you all `sessionId`s that have at least two distinct `codeValue`s.